# How to use a MySQL user function with PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, user-defined-functions

This is what I've coined up, the code doesn't work and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

For example I don't know how I'm supposed to register my function - how to inject it in relation to the query etc. Could someone tell me how to write this piece of code correctly?

error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
 error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELI
MITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION my_sum(int1 INT, int2 INT)
  RETURNS INT
  LANG' at line 1' in mysql_test.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 mysql_test.php(18): PDO->exec('DELIMITER $$\r\nC...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in mysql_test.php on line 18
```

the code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_db;charset=utf8", 'root');
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (col1 INT, col2 INT);");
for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $db->exec("INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(".rand().",".rand().");");
}
$mysql_function = <<<'NOW'
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION my_sum(int1 INT, int2 INT)
  RETURNS INT
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  RETURN int1+int2;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
NOW;
$db->exec($mysql_function);
$db->query("SELECT my_sum(col1, col2) FROM test_table")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Just a tip: You don't need to concatenate in PHP's `rand()` output. You can call `RAND()` natively in MySQL, and you don't need a loop:  `INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (RAND(),RAND()),(RAND(),RAND()),(RAND(),RAND()),(RAND(),RAND());`  Separate multiple inserts by `(),(),()` in the `VALUES`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `<<<'NOW'` is nowdoc syntax, as you will see if you read the page you've kindly linked to.

Comment: @lonesomeday edit: sorry, I thought it was heredoc.

Comment: You shouldn't be running this kind of query as part of your normal code anyway... stuff like this should be done directly in `mysql` from the command line, or through PHPMyAdmin or a similar GUI.

Comment: The `DELIMITER` is a client feature of the MySQL command line client, it is _not_ a normal MySQL syntax feature and will generate a syntax error if you try to use it in a PDO query.

Comment: As @NiettheDarkAbsol says, the real question here is "Why are you trying to create a function in a MySQL database from PHP code?"

Comment: @lonesomeday: to have it available in other scripting languages, I'm not sure I will be using these queries in php so if it's possible I try to write much logic in sql. I's sometimes more convenient to have one point of change..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mysql` driver does not support multi-statement queries. Therefore, `DELIMITER` makes no sense in a query, and the result is that it is a syntax error to try and use it.

You should be able to just have:

```
$mysql_function = <<<'NOW'
CREATE FUNCTION my_sum(int1 INT, int2 INT)
  RETURNS INT
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  RETURN int1+int2;
END;
NOW;
```

However, `CREATE FUNCTION` is a [Data Definition Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html) and you should probably never have such statements in your PHP-run queries. Table structures and functions should be defined when you're setting up the server, using one-time-use queries such as from a `.sql` file, through the `mysql` command line, or an administration GUI like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Minor quibbling: `mysqli` does support [multiple statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php).

Comment: @JaredFarrish That is does, however this particular case uses PDO and the `mysql` driver.

Comment: `new PDO("` **`mysql`** `:host=localhost...`

Answer (score 0):

Execute the function creation in individual steps:

```
$db->exec('DELIMITER $$');
$db->exec('CREATE FUNCTION my_sum(int1 INT, int2 INT)
  RETURNS INT
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  RETURN int1+int2;
END $$');
$db->exec('DELIMITER ;');
```